# Angular log4j vulnarability

Tags: angular

Does anyone know if an Angular application is exposed to the log4j vulnerability? Google search did not bring much. I'm using Angular 13 with the Devextreme components.

In the node_modules directory there is a directory with the name log4js. But I cannot figure out if that one is used somewhere. Also not if that is the same as the log4js that is vulnareble since on the package site https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js it mention that although the package has the same name, it is not the same.

All in all confusing for me since I'm not an expert on that area.

Can anyone help me out here?
Thanks

Comment: Log4j is a server-side vulnerability that is present in a logging package in the *java* language. Front-end frameworks do not contribute to or affect the severity of this vulnerability.

Comment: Here's an explainer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-abhd-CLwQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're all good, log4j is a Java library for server side.

You're using a javascript client-side framework(Angular) which isn't affected by Log4J vulnerability even though your package name looks similar :)

And as mentionned on the npm package site :

`Although it's got a similar name to the Java library log4j, thinking that it will behave the same way will only bring you sorrow and confusion.`